# Cannot see value passed from grails controller in view

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a grails app, with a controller like -

```
def query = {

def options = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']

if (some criteria matches) {
  render(view: "queryws", model: [opts: options])
 }
}
```

In my gsp, I am trying to retrieve value as -

```
<tr>
<td><label for="env">Options:</label></td>
<td><g:select name="env"
from="${opts.list()}" id="select"
value="${params.env}" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't see `params.env`? You're only passing `opts` in your model.

Comment: No, I am not seeing the "opts" in the drop down.

Comment: Try just `from="${opts}"` instead of with that `.list()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You only need `from="${opts}"`, as the *from* tag [takes a list or range](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

there is no `env` is passed from controller .
print the `${opts}` is in gsp page. if  is array then it will work..
for example

```
<g:select name="env" from="${['X', 'Y', 'Z']}"
          value="" />
```

Comment: I dont want to populate the list in the gsp, but need it be passed at runtime. Hence, this wont work -from="${['X', 'Y', 'Z']}